# phonegap listview

Tags: android, cordova

I want to build an attractive list by using `phonegap`.I need to have good `listview` as per requirement and that can be possible by only `phonegap` but i don't know much about `phonegap` so  please give me some links to tutorial and examples of `phonegap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jquery mobile for making a good looking listview. [See](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/index.html) Jquery Mobile docs for more information. For knowing in depth about phonegap [look here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/index.html). Hope this is what you were searching for.

Answer (score 1):

For latest phonegap documentation,  [see here](http://docs.phonegap.com/)